# Amazon Neptune Naming Convention

Tags: neo4j, naming-conventions, graph-databases, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Naming Convention in Neo4j is very clear:

- **Node** (Vertex): UpperCamelCase (Pascal case)
- **Relation** (Edge) : UPPER_CASE
- **Property**: lowerCamelCase

Is the above an agreed naming convention for all graph databases?

In case not, what is the naming convention of Amazon Neptune / Apache TinkerPop?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably better to ask the question in the context of Apache TinkerPop style property graphs in general regardless of the actual database being used. I have not seen much in the way of recommended naming conventions for TinkerPop enabled graph stores. I do see the UPPER_CASE style of edge label used quite a lot but it is definitely not universally used. For properties I have seen quite a lot of just lowercase and lower_snake_case used but also lowerCamelCase. For vertex labels I have mostly seen all lowercase or UpperCamelCase.

To a large extent this just comes down to stylistic preference. None of the choices made should have much impact on graph data interoperability and I have not found this to be a topic that comes up too often with people building property graphs.

Bottom line, i am not aware of anyone having tried to define a convention for TinkerPop enabled graph stores. I would use what feels most natural to you.

I would be interested in any ideas @StephenMallette has on this from a TinkerPop perspective.